# Netstat dosent exist in my debian linux bash shell

Tags: bash, debian

I installed Debian plasma and netstat just dosent exist. every time Ive typed in netstat it says "bash: netstat: command not found"

Comment: Install Netstat in Debian:      ...........   https://www.tecmint.com/install-netstat-in-linux/   ...... I do not use a bash shell, but Netstat is running in Kali and Ubuntu.

Comment: have you tried running it with Sudo? some distro configurations require sudo for commands like ifconfig, and print the same error if you don't use it, so worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern Linux distros have replaced `netstat`with `ss`, so you might want to check if what you were trying to do with `netstat` can equally be achieved with `ss`.

For most common use cases both programs take the same options, e.g. `netstat -lant` does the same as `ss -lant` (although the output looks slightly different). For further details I suggest you view the respective man pages: [netstat(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/net-tools/netstat.8.de.html) vs. [ss(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/iproute2/ss.8.en.html).

Comment: You could improve your answer by givi4a synopsis of the commands

Comment: I feel that copying the synopsis that can be found at the top of each man page would bloat my answer unnecessarily. I linked the man pages a bit more prominently, hope this'll do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why `netstat` *should* be present in your system since it's not one of POSIX-defined utilities. You can check out the current list of those [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html).

Because it's not in POSIX (which is a standard that Linux distributions like Debian tend to stick to), it's really up to the distribution version whether they decide to include it or not.

To install it, first update your repositories (to find the newest version, always a good idea before installation).

```sh
sudo apt update
```

And then you should be able to install it.

```sh
sudo apt install net-tools
```